# Use OR operand on BOOL (tinyint(1)) Fields MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use the **OR** operand when comparing two boolean values?

Using MYSQL 5+

Ex.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
table1.3_InMarket = (table1.3_InMarket OR b.3_InMarket),
```

I want to set the True value to the field if one exists between the new and the old.

Both those fields are set to tinyint(1) aka Bool.

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: Do you know that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is part of an insert statement? It doesn't stand alone.

Comment: Yes, Yes. I didnt want to share all my code :p

I tested it using SELECT TRUE OR FALSE; and it seems to work. Just wanted a second opionon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the behavior with a simple table.

```
drop table test;
create table test (
  n integer not null,
  tf boolean not null default false,
  primary key (n)
);
-- Starts false, set to true.
insert into test values (1, false);
insert into test values (1, false) on duplicate key update tf = (tf or true);
-- Starts false, does not set to true.
insert into test values (2, false);
insert into test values (2, false) on duplicate key update tf = (tf or false);
-- Starts true, set to true.
insert into test values (3, true);
insert into test values (3, true) on duplicate key update tf = (tf or true);
-- Starts true, does not set to false.
insert into test values (4, true);
insert into test values (4, true) on duplicate key update tf = (tf or true);

select * from test;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worth checking so that you better understand it as a developer, but this should be perfectly possible.